# Does QBuffer write data in system dependent byte order?

Tags: qt

The documentation says that QDataStream writes data in system independent way, but it says nothing about QBuffer. I develop a program that saves data in a file like this:

```
QByteArray a;
QBuffer b(&a);
b.open(QIODevide::WriteOnly);
quint32 x = 1;
b.write((char*)&x, sizeof(x));
b.close();
QFile f(...);
f.open(QIODevide::WriteOnly);
f.write(a.constData(), a.size());
f.close();
```

, and i want this file can be read in any other OS (win, linux, Mac OS). Will this code work or i must use QDataStream instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [QBuffer documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qbuffer.html#details) says :

> The QBuffer class provides a QIODevice interface for a QByteArray.

ie it is only a `QByteArray` underneath. On the other hand a `QByteArray` is portable because as long as you see the data as an array of byte and write one byte at a time you are fine. Your code will work:

When you say

> I want this file to be read in any other OS

Is your file used by your program only or will it be used by other applications in the system? `QDataStream` provides nicer functions for `I\O` and you may be still able to take advantage of it.

---

It will be platform specific. `x` representation in memory depend on the endianess.It doesn't occur in the `QBuffer`, but when you do :

```
b.write((char*)&x, sizeof(x));
```

If you are on machines of different endianess, you will obtain different values for the resulting array by doing

```
char* data = &x;
qDebug()<< data[0];
qDebug()<< data[1];
qDebug()<< data[2];
qDebug()<< data[3];
```

Take a look at the source code of [QDataStream operator](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/corelib/io/qdatastream.cpp#line1045)

```
QDataStream &QDataStream::operator<<(qint32 i){

  CHECK_STREAM_WRITE_PRECOND(*this)
  if (!noswap) {
      i = qbswap(i);
  }
   if (dev->write((char *)&i, sizeof(qint32)) != sizeof(qint32))
       q_status = WriteFailed;
   return *this;
}
```

Comment: Actually i write a few bytes at a time, like int32 in example. So i wonder if 32-bit variable will be written in platform specific byte order or not?

Comment: Thanks, this is what i wanted to know